# How can I make a object follow perfectly a nurb path?

Tags: modifiers, path

I'm currently making a track for Assetto Corsa. I make the tracks with objects that follow paths but i'm always having some issues to make the objects follow properly the path. This time is this what happens:
[image: problem]
Note: The selected object is that one which I want to follow the path without curve modifier.

So I have 2 questions:
1. How can I solve this?
2. Is there any way I  can make a object follow perfectly a nurb path?

I leave my [.blend](https://mega.nz/#!YkE2CaCA!6nv30jaMQs1NGqvjKAhPaiqsrP5gdx1kX3m7vV8Ubv4) so you can check it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Usually, this is a problem of object origin being at the wrong place

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, delete all objects except NurbsCirle and Cube.000. They are not relevant to the problem and only in the way.
- Set the cursor at the world origin (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). Select all objects (<kbd>A</kbd>) and set the objects origin to cursor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
- Select you object and go into edit mode. You'll see it is not at the origin. Select all Vertices and in the Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) -> Transform -> Median, set all values to 0 to center your object. Rotate it until it doesn't lay flat on the ground. Exit edit mode.
- In the Modifiers panel of your object, make sure there is an Array modifier with its length set to "Fit Curve" (If your object doesn't fit the curve later on, remove the curve). Beneath you sould have a Curve modifier set to NurbsCurve. Test all Deformation axes until you hit the right one.
- Select your curve and go into edit mode. Select everything. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to tilt your curve along its path until the object on it is oriented the right way. You may need to do this several times at several locations until it looks like you want.
- You're done. Now you can try to restore the other objects and move the curve's origin without destroying everything

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks man! you just solved my problem but another question comes in: is there any way to make the tilt smooth? I can edit some control points together and i can edit them individually so i have to be very precise on each tilt to make a progressive tilt.

Comment: is there any way to say this to blender: from this control point to that control point, make a progressive tilt from 0 to X degrees. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Tilts are on a per-vertex-base. If it isn't precise enough, select and edge and subdivide it. If you mean the tilt is too fast press shift while tilting.